# mysql not getting the data from php

Tags: php, mysql

mysql cant get this data. maybe there is something wrong with my query? because the query dies. thanks a lot

```
include "../../functions/connect.php";
extract($_POST);


if(isset($add)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_patients`(`dateadd`,`pfname`,`plname`,`pdob`,`address`,`pgender`,`pbtype`,`pheight`,`pweight`,`fallergy`,`mallergy`)
    VALUES ('$dateadd','$fname','$lname','$dob','$address','$gender','$bloodtype','$hgt','$wgt','$falrgs','malrgs')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Verification Error");
if($result)
    {
        $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_patients` WHERE `pfname` = '$fname' ");
        $aa = mysql_fetch_array($a);

        if($a)
        {
            $aaa = $aa['patientid'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_medhistory`(`patientid`, `disease`, `sdate`, `edate`, `tdoctor`, `note`, `active`) VALUES('$aaa','$disease','$sdate','$edate','$doc','$note','$act')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('succesfully Registered THANK YOU!')</script>";

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: i dont know . it calls the die in $result which is verification error. i dont know how to check the error -_-

Comment: Change it to `die("Verification Error: " . mysql_error());` and show what turns up.

Comment: Verification Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: saw the error . it was in the height. i was using 5'7" where the sql cant read it as that. thanks btw :)

Comment: Pleasure mate, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `mysql_error()` in your `die()` like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Verification Error: ".mysql_error());
```

That way you can see the sql error you're getting.

I suggest you add it to all your mysql_query() just in case another fails.

Also keep in mind that you should escape your values before using them in a sql to prevent sql injection or errors because of using quotes in the values:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php